# remote host has disconnected error with sshfs as cron job on openbsd

Tags: networking, ssh, cron, sshfs, openbsd

I am trying to automount a directory with sshfs using crontab. the sshfs command:

```
/usr/local/bin/sshfs -o IdentityFile=/home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub,idmap=user,allow_other,uid=1000,gid=1000 user@website:/home/public/ /home/user/website
```

works when run with doas and also run as root. But when run through cron as:

```
*       *       *       *       *       df | grep website || /usr/local/bin/sshfs -o IdentityFile=/home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub,idmap=user,allow_other,uid=1000,gid=1000 user@website:/home/public/ /home/user/website
```

cron emails the mail server:

```
Auto-Submitted: auto-generated
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/var/log> 
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=root>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=root>

remote host has disconnected
```

any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Cheers,
Freddie xxx

Edit: adding debug output below:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/   root/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/root/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "website.net" port 22
debug3: resolve_host: lookup website:22
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to website [204.13.88.49] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub type 3
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_9.6
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_9.6 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to website:22 as 'user'
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 3 keys from website
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /root/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: have matching best-preference key type ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com, using HostkeyAlgorithms verbatim
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-s,kex-strict-s-v00@openssh.com
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:etjM+pc9ujAYv0M7gTAiLUHdZe0nAxlEQ2PRIdEjvRE
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 3 keys from website
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /root/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'website' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub ED25519 SHA256:xd0TyATzyTHbz7bE8UQdhJ8sLgEsVjjwHA76TRroioY explicit
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256>
debug1: kex_ext_info_check_ver: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com=<0>
debug1: kex_ext_info_check_ver: ping@openssh.com=<0>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub ED25519 SHA256:xd0TyATzyTHbz7bE8UQdhJ8sLgEsVjjwHA76TRroioY explicit
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub ED25519 SHA256:xd0TyATzyTHbz7bE8UQdhJ8sLgEsVjjwHA76TRroioY explicit
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: using publickey-hostbound-v00@openssh.com with ED25519 SHA256:xd0TyATzyTHbz7bE8UQdhJ8sLgEsVjjwHA76TRroioY
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using ssh-ed25519 SHA256:xd0TyATzyTHbz7bE8UQdhJ8sLgEsVjjwHA76TRroioY Load key "/home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub": invalid format
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: Device not configured
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password Permission denied, please try again.    
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: Device not configured
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password     Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: Device not configured
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
user@website: Permission denied (publickey,password).
remote host has disconnected
```

Comment: In Debian I can use `sshfs -d -o LogLevel=DEBUG3 …` to get debug information from `sshfs` *and* from `ssh` it uses as transport. Try with these options, hopefully they will work and cron will e-mail much more useful things to you. Then obfuscate what you want to obfuscate (if anything) and post what you got.

Comment: thanks, have added the debug log to the post

Comment: Now we're talking. :) Note you can compare this output to the debug output of a successful connection and maybe you will find some clue on your own.

Comment: `"/home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub": invalid format` – Is it possible `sshfs` from cron and `sshfs` from a shell use different `ssh` executables? and only one of them understands the format of the key? `PATH` in cron seems to be `/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin`. Invoke `echo "$PATH"` in a shell and compare. In Bash use `type ssh` to find which exact `ssh` you use when invoking from the command line. Any progress?

Comment: Thanks! i did notice that in the log! `echo $PATH` is `/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin` and the ssh in use is `ssh is /usr/bin/ssh`! so how would i change what ssh cron was using is the next thing i guess?

Comment: Is there `/sbin/ssh` different than `/usr/bin/ssh`?

Comment: there is no ssh in /sbin/

Comment: OK, the hypothesis has failed. There is no `ssh` in `/bin` (otherwise the shell would use it), there is no `ssh` in `/sbin`, so the next to try from cron is `/usr/bin` which gives you *the* `ssh` the shell uses.

Comment: Does `.pub` mean you're giving a *public* key to point `ssh` to the corresponding private key loaded to an `ssh-agent` maybe?

Comment: Not sure i understand exactly what you mean? in my users .ssh folder their is one `.pub` (public key) and one private, which is just `id_ed25519`. I thought i was meant to send the`.pub` public key to the server?

Comment: `-o IdentityFile=` does not send a key to the server. It picks a key `ssh` will use to authenticate you (i.e. to solve challenges from the server, they can only be solved by using secret information from the private key). You can specify a public key, but [this is only to pick the desired private key provided by an agent](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/722146/108618). If your `.pub` key is a public key then probably `sshfs` from a shell works because there is an agent with the right private key; cron has no variables to find the agent. Specify the private key.

Comment: Thank you! thats that sorted, sorry for the hassle x

Comment: Well, you can now [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer). There is no need to mention my input, keep the answer technical.